# Generar archivos .pyc en Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.x, compilador

Quiero generar los compilados .pyc a partir de scripts .py en Python 2.6.6.
La siguiente línea funciona en Python 2.7:

```
python -m compileall C:\una_ruta\myscript.py
```

Si hago lo mismo en Python 2.6.6 (incluso pasándole las rutas completas):

```
C:\Python26\python -m compileall C:\una_ruta\myscript.py
```

Me bota el siguiente error:

> Listing myscript.py ...
>
> Can't list myscript.py

Estoy usando Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: Ya probaste compilarlos desde la carpeta donde lo tienes?

Comment: Porque quieres generar archivos pyc, porque si es por ofuscar, no suman nada, son facilmente decompilables, solo ayudan a mejorar tiempos de ejecución pero nada mas, osea ejecuta el codigo y solo tendras que generarlo la primera ves.

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga no quiero ofuscar el código, si no hacer más difícil que alguien pueda sabotearlo (meter una línea como 'subprocess.call("mv /dev/sda1 /dev/null")'), pues está pensado para correr en Linux con privilegios de root por un tercero. Si se tienen sólo los .pyc no hay posibilidad de que alguien altere el código "por error", lo tendría que hacer alguien con la plena intención de hacer el mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En python 2.6 para Windows lo que funciona es esto:

```
C:\Python26\python -m py_compile C:\una_ruta\myscript.py
```